# Dynamically importing Typescript file as an alternative to json-based config

Tags: typescript, aws-cdk

Here's the background:
We're developing [AWS CDK](https://aws.amazon.com/cdk/) modules using Typescript (fyi I'm not very experienced in TS).

For example, there will be a module for representing a container-based app which deveopers can use to provision their service. Very high-level, each app's "definition" will be something like (very high-level):

```js
import {containerApp} from 'CompanyContainerApp'
const environment = callSomeMethodToFindEnv() // for example, 'prod'
config = import('/prod')
const myApp = new containerApp(`myapp-${environment}`, config)
```

So the challenge here is that 'prod' and 'dev' represent differnt config values, that need to be sent to the constructor of `containerApp`. I could of course go with simple json files and parse them, but these configs can be complex, and having them in a type would make it much easier to express which config attributes are required, which are optional etc.

Right now this is my code:

```js
// cat index.ts
import {Config} from './configdefinition'

export function hello(word: string = world): string {
    const envName = 'prod'
    const config: Config = import(`./${envName}`)
    return `Hello2 ${world}! `
}
hello()


// cat configdefinition.ts
export class Config {
    // props with defaults
    readonly numberOfLegs: number = 8
    constructor(
        // required props
        readonly name: string,
        readonly lastname?: string
    ) {}
}


// cat prod.ts
import {Config} from './configdefinition'
const config = new Config(
    'prodman',
    'wakka'
)
export default config
```

Typescript complains that 'config' is a "promise" and not an instance of the `Config` class.
I'm aware this is an open question but I guess I'm trying to figure out if this is possible at all, or if I should just stick to old-school json for my configs (which would be a shame but it wouldn't kill us).

As stands right now, ts complains that my `config` const is really a promise, not an instance of the `Confg`class - it looks like using the `import` function will cast me into the dark chasms of having to deal with promises etc and I was hoping to avoid that.

So I guess this is a bit of an open-ended question but to sum up:
1. Should I just give up and use json-based configs instead
2. If no, what would be the correct way to dynamically import another class instance, whill still maintaining "strong" types? (e.g. to know that the `config` object is an instance of `Config`)

Any pointers deeply appreciated, I'm *quite* new to Typescript.

UPDATE: A reply sent me in the right direct, i'm exploring using promises for now. This is what I've come up with so far:

```js
// cat configdefinition
export class Config {
    // props with defaults
    readonly numberOfLegs: number = 8
    constructor(
        // required props
        readonly name: string,
        readonly lastname?: string
    ) {}
}


// cat prod.ts
import {Config} from './configdefinition'
export const config: Config = new Config('Bobba', 'Fett')

//cat index.ts
import {Config} from './configdefinition'

export function doSomeStuff(config: any) {
    // @ts-ignore
    const thisConfig: Config = config.config
    console.log(thisConfig.lastname)
}

export function hello() {
    const envName = 'prod'
    const configImport: Promise<Config> = import(`./${envName}`)
    configImport.then(
        result => doSomeStuff(result)
    )
}
hello()
```

So this works I had to add a ts-ignore to "force" typescript to dynamically extract the `config`attribute of the dynamic import. I suspect there are ways to do this that don't require this type of rule-breaking but as it stands I'm happy with this. Hope this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 1):

The following is working for me:

just modified :

```
const config: Promise<Config> = import(`./${envName}`)
```

Complete working code in one module:

```
function hello(word: string = 'world'): string {
    const envName = 'prod'
    const config: Promise<Config> = import(`./${envName}`)
    return `Hello2 ${word}! `
}
console.log(hello());


// cat configdefinition.ts
 class Config {
    // props with defaults
    readonly numberOfLegs: number = 8
    constructor(
        // required props
        readonly name: string,
        readonly lastname?: string
    ) {}
}


// cat prod.ts

const config = new Config(
    'prodman',
    'wakka'
);
```

or better use async await func like :

```
async function hello(word: string = 'world'): Promise<string> {
  const envName = 'prod'
  const config: Config = await import(`./${envName}`)
  return `Hello2 ${word}! `
}
console.log(hello());
```

Comment: Thanks for replying! Simply switching to `Promise<Config>` doesn't seem to resolve the promise, it just outputs `<pending>` when I log it.

I was hoping to avoid doing async, I'm not even sure the cdk tool I'm using supports it. But I'll definetely research if that's an option. Your async example works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: yes because it's a promise.. use config.then(result => console.log), or better async await way...

Comment: nice. This pointed me in the right direction, updated my answer. Thanks again!